# creating a loop for a simulation with linked variables in r

Tags: r, average

I'm simulating species richness based on extinction and speciation rates using the sim.bd function from the geiger package. I need to run the simulation 1000 times. When you run it once you get 3 columns of data:

```
    time   n
[1]   1    6
[2] .....
```

What I want after the simulation has run 1000 times is the average n for each time. I know to create a loop to get this far:

```r
c.sprich<-c()   
for (i in 100) 
{
pop.carn <- sim.bd(b=0.39, d=0.55, n0=4, times=66)
c.sprich[i]<- ##I don't know what command to put here to get the average n linked to each time 
}
```

Any ideas?

I've tried functions like length() but that results in the sum of everything and not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a `base-R` approach based on `replicate()` and `rowMeans()` like so:

```
library(geiger)
set.seed(1) # to make results reproducible
sim <- replicate(1000, sim.bd(b = .39, d = .55, n0 = 4L, times = 1:66L)[, "n"]) |>
  {\(x) cbind("time" = 0L:66L, "AveragePerN" = round(rowMeans(x), digits = 3L)) }()
```

gives

```
> head(sim)
     time AveragePerN
[1,]    0       4.000
[2,]    1       3.131
[3,]    2       2.672
[4,]    3       2.306
[5,]    4       1.978
[6,]    5       1.624
```

(1) `replicate()` "is a loop" which executes `sim.bd()` 1,000 times. As we are interested in the `n`, we only collect those from each `sim.bd()`-run. We do not want the time column to be printed 1,000 times, since nothing changes there.
(2) We then column-bind the vector of times with the row means. Additionally, we round those averages returned from `rowMeans()` by 3 digits. This, of course, is optional.

Comment: You are a god. Not only does the code work but I actually understand why you did everything, thank you so much!!